# Correlated LINQ Query Optimization

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to fetch the changed records, in which the Ignition of Vehicle Changed. Here is my SQL table.

[image]

i.e I want to fetch record 47890 and and record 47879.

i've written the following correlated LINQ query.

```
var sData = (from log in db.GSMDeviceLogs
             where log.Vehicle.VehicleId == vehicleId
             where log.IgnitionOn != (from prevLog in db.GSMDeviceLogs
                                     where prevLog.Vehicle.VehicleId == vehicleId
                                     where prevLog.DateTimeOfLog < log.DateTimeOfLog
                                     orderby prevLog.DateTimeOfLog descending
                                     select prevLog.IgnitionOn).FirstOrDefault()
             orderby log.DateTimeOfLog ascending
             select new { LogId = log.GSMDeviceLogId,
                          Ignition = log.IgnitionOn,
                          Date = log.DateTimeOfLog,
                          Location = log.Location }).ToList();
```

It gives the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Inner Exception Says:

```
{"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}
```

I hope this is due to the query being very inefficient and taking too much time to execute. How can we optimize the LINQ query?

Comment: There can be thousands of records for the vehicle. Loading everything in memory would make it very slow.

Comment: You can't know without trying. It all depends on your design. Querying this type of sequential data (e.g. timeseries) in a relational database won't be very efficient either -- you'll need to run a subquery for every record. I'd look at writing a stored procedure that uses a cursor (yes -- this is a perfectly valid use of cursors), or even write a [CLR SQL stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Please highlight records `47890` and `47879` on your screenshot. Finding them yourself causes eye strain.

Answer (score 0):

It is all right, you could probably do something more efficient with a nice sproc or some magic SQL. But let's say you can't, for whatever reason. It does not mean you have to either give up or run some SELECT N+1 code. If you properly order your sequence (as you are already doing) you can scan your sequence just once with Linq and use some smart extension method to remember the previous value. With something like this in your toolbox:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TR> Pair<T, TR>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, TR> resultor)
    {
        return PairImpl<T, TR>(source, resultor);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TR> PairImpl<T, TR>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, TR> resultor)
    {
        var e = source.GetEnumerator();
        var a = default(T);

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            var b = e.Current;
            yield return resultor(a, b);
            a = b;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then write an expression like this:

```
var logs = 
    from log in db.GSMDeviceLogs
    where log.Vehicle.VehicleId == vehicleId
    orderby log.DateTimeOfLog ascending
    select log;

var diffs = 
    from log in logs.Pair((a, b) => new { a, b })
    where log.a != null && log.a.IgnitionOn != log.b.IgnitionOn
    select log.a;
```

This scans *in memory* all your records, but just once, and it does it in an expressive way. As said, doing it at the database level would be more efficient, but maybe you can't go there.

The [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project is packed with extension methods like the one I roughly suggest here.

Comment: This one will bring all the records from db and perform diff as linq to objects query.

Comment: I know, I said that in the answer, and I also said when it could still be useful.

Comment: Agreed with Marcin. And yes, i have already done something like this. Bringing everything in memory. But I have around 50-60K records for one vehicle and bringing everything in takes considerable time. That why, I was looking for something which would only bring changed records from db.

Comment: Just to clarify, you already tried something like the code I described? Because your code from the question is completely different, most likely triggering a lot of queries towards the database because of the inner query. What I describe is still somewhat "brute force", but it's just one query, and 50-60K of records like yours should not take a long time. I don't want to sell my idea at all costs :) but if you get timeouts with something like that then you might have other issues going on too.

Comment: I did a test with 50K records and Linq to SQL (it was quicker to write with Linqpad, but EF should not be much worse) and that query runs in less than 50ms...

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join:

```
var sData = (from log in db.GSMDeviceLogs
             join log2 in db.GSMDeviceLogs on log.GSMDeviceLogId equals log2.GSMDeviceLogId - 1
             where log.Vehicle.VehicleId == vehicleId
                 && log.IgnitionOn != log2.IgnitionOn
             orderby log.DateTimeOfLog ascending
             select new { LogId = log.,
                          Ignition = log.IgnitionOn,
                          Date = log.DateTimeOfLog,
                          Location = log.Location }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is nice, but it also assumes id are always consecutive (I mean, no holes), which might be ok, but might be not.

Comment: Rightly said Wasp.And that is the actual scenario, there might be other vehicle record in the -1 place. That's why i used date.